# How to resolve integrated files in Perforce JAVA API

Tags: java, perforce, resolve

How to resolve integrated files in Perforce JAVA API. I am trying to merge files from one branch to another. I am using following code to merge.

```
tmpClient.integrateFiles(file,  toFile, "17.2",  opts );
```

After executing this command, files need to be resolved. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean: "how can I write a program which automatically merges and resolves these files"? Or do you mean: "how can I use a visual merge tool to resolve the pending integrations that my Java program has scheduled for me"? In the general case, a human being has to inspect and resolve merge conflicts when integrating changes between files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at IClient.resolveFile() and IClient.resolveFilesAuto():

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/p4java-javadoc/com/perforce/p4java/client/IClient.html

The specific method you use will depend on whether you expect that you will always be able to rely on auto-resolve (which is a bad expectation generally) and what sort of system you have in your app to handle conflicting merges.