# how to merge changelist into another branch using perforce java api

Tags: java, merge, perforce, changelist

how to merge changelist into another branch using perforce java api. I have submitted some changes into a Perforce branch and a changelist created. Now I want to merge that changelist into another branches, using Perforce JAVA API.

I want to know if there is any method to merge single changelist into branch instead of merging files one by one using Perforce JAVA API.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve integrated files in Perforce JAVA API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38562749/how-to-resolve-integrated-files-in-perforce-java-api)

Comment: This one is different. I want to know if there is any method to merge single changelist into branch instead of merging files one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the changelist to the IFileSpec that you use as the "from" for the integrateFiles() call.

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/p4java-javadoc/com/perforce/p4java/core/file/IFileSpec.html

The equivalent from the p4 command line is doing:

```
p4 integrate source/...@change,change target/...
```

rather than:

```
p4 integrate source/... target/...
```

Comment: I have used this as follows into Java API, but still now working: `fromIFileSpec.setChangelistId(<changelist-Id-to-integrate>);` Can you check what I am missing here?                                                                      
Exact Code is as follows:

`file.setChangelistId(changelist.getId());
client.integrateFiles(file, toFiles, opts);`

Comment: Try `FileSpec("source/...@change,change")`?

Comment: where I'll put the change-list number, which needs to be integrated?

Comment: I tried this but didn't worked out:- `"source/...@change," + changelist.getId();`

Comment: I tried this but this is merging all changes not just provided change-list number changes:- `"source/...@" + changelist.getId();`

Comment: Now I got it. "source/...@" + changelist.getId() + "," + changelist.getId();

Answer (score 1):

To integrate change-list using Perforce JAVA API, use following code:

```
List<IFileSpec> fromFiles = FileSpecBuilder.makeFileSpecList("source/...@<changelist>,<changelist>");
List<IFileSpec> toFiles = FileSpecBuilder.makeFileSpecList("destination/...");
for (IFileSpec file : fromFiles) {
    client.integrateFiles(file, toFiles, opts);
    client.resolveFilesAuto(toFiles, resolvOptions);
}
```